# Upload upto 10 gb of file on ftp

Tags: c#, file-upload

Here I am uploading upto 10 gb of file on ftp server but it stops the process after 1 gb data upload. Below is my code for upload 1 gb of data.

```
try
{
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName","Password");
    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    using (Stream sourceStream = File.OpenRead("D:/data.zip"))
    using (Stream reqStrm = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        int i = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024]; //1 MB buffer
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            i = i + 1;
            count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(buffer.Length + " "+i);
                reqStrm.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0);
    }
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
}
```

Can we upload 10 gb of data with this way ?

Comment: The protocol itself has no limit. Are you sure there is enough available disk space? Are there any restrictions set by the ftp provider? What exception do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops"? What happens? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Kvam and Jon there is no further processing of upload after 788 mb of data. No exception I am getting. But sometime I am getting Unable to write data to the transport connection after 788 mb exception